# Populate a drop-down based off the contents of another using lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, dropdown

I am very new to SharePoint and am having trouble with a few basics I thought were simple, it's a large change from my way of thinking about databases and presentation.

Anyways, I am required to populate one drop down with choices from a list and then, based off what the user chooses, populate a second drop down that should filter data based off the first drop down. I normally understand these produce's using using SQL tables with Keys but I am a bit confused how to go about this here.

I am using SharePoint foundation 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint doesn't give you a way to do this out of the box. You either need to use InfoPath to set up the cascading drop down or create a custom form and use jQuery/Javascript/Client or Server object model to do it.

Comment: sounds fine to me, so the short answer yes it is possible? I am familiare with jQuery using PHP so this seems plausable

Comment: It is, but with script. Since your familiar with jQuery, I'd recommend the SPServices library,  Marc has a function to help with cascading dropdowns, http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation